# Where can I find good programming resources for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have been trying to find a book or web reference that gives me good understanding on how to build, test, and deploy ASP.NET pages, controls, and web parts to a SharePoint web site. All I have found so far is either draggy-droppy stuff or administration stuff.

Is SharePoint really flexible with ASP.NET when is comes to extending it? A series of getting started videos or tutorials would be ideal.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Despite what sales *says* the intent of SharePoint/MOSS is, the architectural intent is for it to be extended via draggy-droppy, widgets-type development. It is a *NIGHTMARE* to do deep, hardcore customizations/development against it. FYI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just ASP.NET and is extenable to a certain limit. It all just depends on what you want to do.

I found the wrox books very usefull:
Professional SharePoint 2007 Development 
Expert WSS 3.0 and MOSS 2007 Programming

Did you check out http://MSSharePointDeveloper.com yet?

Answer (score 2):

Another good developer reference is [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/books/9692.aspx). This is Microsoft's recommended reading for the core WSS developer exam and is often seen as a bible for SharePoint development.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be doing any **Publishing with Sharepoint** Andrew Connell's book [Professional Sharepoint Content Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470224754) is a must read.

Answer (score 1):

From twitter they are announcing [MSDN Office Developer Bookshop today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dd547103.aspx)

http://twitter.com/MSDN_Office

Answer (score 0):

I've had remarkable luck with [PilotHouse Consulting's](http://www.pilothouseconsulting.com) SharePoint development DVD for getting a bunch of the basics for SharePoint development.  I'm going to check out these other answers though.