# Ms SharePoint 2007 Template Customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, templates, ide-customization

After downloading the free templates from Microsoft's site I want to combine some features of two templates together.  For example, there is a "Contact Management" template and a "Marketing Site" template.  Each template has its own "contacts section/form".

Ideally, I want to use both templates on my SharePoint server while having them referring to the same contacts.  Again, currently each has its own contacts.

I expect this to be a fairly simple task, but I'm fairly new to SharePoint and not sure where to start with this task.  I've been looking around, but no luck so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to the Fantastic 40 templates that can be [downloaded from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5807B5EF-57A1-47CB-8666-78C1363F127D&displaylang=en).

I'd like to say otherwise but unfortunately this isn't a simple task! There is no out-of-the-box way to link two different contacts lists to one set of contacts. You can of course develop such a solution.

If you want to get started with programming SharePoint, [have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501776/where-can-i-find-good-programming-resources-for-sharepoint) for some useful resources. [This document](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C49A6B00-E0AA-4102-B585-B25CD3CBB383&displaylang=en) might also be helpful in researching the templates themselves further.